# How to add authorship to NumPy docstring, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-sphinx, docstring

We switched from [Sphinx](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/rest_syntax.html#metainformation) to style NumPy docstring and `.. sectionauthor::` no longer seems to render correctly. Yet, we need to be able to assign an author to each method of a class.

Is there a way to add authorship to NumPy docstring properly?

A naive example:

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        """ My function

        It does this and that.

        Returns
        -------
        object

        .. sectionauthor:: name of the author

        Examples
        --------
            >>> A().f()

        """
        pass
```

Compiles into this help doc (notice troubled **returns:** section):

[image]

P.S. Use of `.. sectionauthor::` in NumPy docstring was suggested elsewhere (can't recall the source), so maybe it is simply not used/placed correctly.

Comment: What are you using to render the `docstring`.  I'm not aware of `numpy` having it's own style or rendering engine (distinct from Python `docstring`).

Comment: Rendering is built into PyCharm, but I do not know what package PyCharm uses. It is done via Quick Documentation tool (or CTRL+Q) and produces an html (I think) output that is shown in printscreen above.

Comment: OK, this is metadata in `reStructuredText`, that is probably being rendered by `docutils`.

Answer (score 7):

figured it out...

First of all, [NumPy style documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt#documenting-modules) discourages addition of authors' info to docstring: "*Note that license and author info, while often included in source files, do not belong in docstrings.*"

That said, it is not uncommon to identify authors directly in documentation (see any help manual for functions/methods in R language).

Still, shall there be a need to add authors, this can be done with `:Authors:` [reStructured inline markup](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#hyperlink-targets) tag, as following:

```
:Authors:
    John Doe <John.Doe@email.com>
```

As discovered, its placement is limited. `:Authors:` seems to still render docstring correctly, if placed away from descriptions, parameters, and returns sections; for example, after `Examples` section.

Here is a continued example:

[image]

Comment: That's a corner of numpy I haven't payed much attention to, though  I read the function docs all the time.